# Advanced Filter Data NOT Getting Copied to Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the Advanced Filter in Excel in VBA and to copy the filtered data to another workbook. The Code is running but no copy in the destination I selected somehow. I get a blank sheet where i need to see the result. I checked and when I filter manually it shows me the rihgt rows in the original place. `ListsWS` is the WS where the criteria is and `OverWS` is where the data stored. Iwant to copy the filtered data to `tmpFile` to worksheet 1 here is my code:

```
        Public myExtension As String
        Public FullPath As String
        Public VisualWB As Workbook
        Public tmpFile As Workbook
        Public VisualWS As Worksheet
        Public LR As Long
        Public lastcol As Integer
        Public MonCol As Integer
        Public Table As Range
        Public SigilDes As Integer
        Public LR_Over As Long

        Sub Export_File()

        Set tmpFile = Application.Workbooks.Add

        With tmpFile
            .Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(1).Name = "over"
            .Worksheets(2).Name = "double"
        End With

        End Sub
        .
        .
        .
        'here is some not relevant code
    Sub Analyze_1()

    'copy monthly and hourly employees with over 42 to new workbook with advanced filter
    With OverWS

        LR_Over = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1", .Cells(LR_Over, lastcol + 2)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
         CriteriaRange:=ListsWS.Range("G1:H3"), CopyToRange:=tmpFile.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), Unique:=False
        .Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `Action:=xlFilterinPlace` to `Action:=xlFilterCopy`

Comment: @DarrellH it works, post it as an answer and i will give you score. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Action:=xlFilterinPlace` to `Action:=xlFilterCopy`